# Not able to connect Mysql with Spring tool suite?

Tags: java, mysql, rest, spring-boot, dependencies

**Should the tomcat port and mysql port be same ?** 
I want to access mysql databases via rest-apis. I'm not able to open mysql workbench and run spring boot at the same time. Is it because both are using the same port? Also if I change the port - "server.port=7070"- in application.properties the project does not run successfully.

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/playjava?useSSL=flase
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port=3306
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>RestWithJPACreateProfessor</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>RestWithJPACreateProfessor</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have a typo in spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/playjava?useSSL=flase

(flase instead of false)
I dont know if it is your problem

Comment: The server port and mysql port should not be the same indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall and reinstall spring tool suite and mysql. Also I had to uninstall tomcat which was running(independently) on my computer due to which I couldn't use port 8080. Which is why I was using port 3306 for spring project as well as mysql. Hence i couldn't simultaneously open mysql while the project was running.